# Android setText on TextView when Callback is finished

Tags: java, android

Hello I have such a code: `pointsToAssignTv.setText(String.valueOf(restData.getPointsUnass(login)));` where `restData.getPointsUnass(login)` is such a Retrofit code:

```
    public int getPointsUnass(String name) {
    Call<String> result = Api.getClient().getPointsUnass(name);
    result.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            pointsUnass = Integer.parseInt(response.body());
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("tag",t.toString());
        }
    });
    return pointsUnass;
}
```

I want to assign this value to this TextView but it returns null, I guess it is all about time it needs to process through the internet and then return. What piece of code would you recommend to write instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the setText() statement to onResponse() callback method. Just add this statement -  `pointsToAssignTv.setText(String.valueOf(pointUnass));`  to onResponse() method.

Comment: Yes this is one method, but is there another one?

Comment: @Jawegiel Are you following any app architecture in your app?

Answer (score 0):

After get response from API, in the `onResponse` should add `someText.setText(yourResponse)`
Notice: be care about threading, in android you just allow change UI element in the main thread, if you want to change the text in response you must use handler

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
}
});
```